# What filters are applied to the_content function?

Tags: theme-development, filters

How does WordPress convert raw data from the database to a readable format in the_content function?

I've noticed that it applies the_content filter, but what does the_content filter do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the default filters are set in /wp-includes/default-filters.php;

for 'the_content' this is from line 135:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize'        );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies'    );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_chars'      );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop'            );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop'  );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prepend_attachment' );
```

to trace the individual functions, you could try and use http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?_functions/index.html
then follow the links...

## Edit

Missed one (`wp-includes/default-filters.php`, line 102):

```
// Format WordPress
foreach ( array( 'the_content', 'the_title' ) as $filter )
    add_filter( $filter, 'capital_P_dangit', 11 );
```

Comment: Shouldn't 'do_shortcode' be in there somewhere? (https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L542)

Answer (score 2):

All filters are stored in the global `$wp_filter` variable. You can inspect that variable to see which functions are bound to a certain filter.

```
global $wp_filter;
print_r($wp_filter['the_content']);
```

To exactly understand the array that gets outputted, knowing how the `$wp_filter` variable is built up helps a lot. This line is from the source of the `add_filter()` function:

```
$wp_filter[$tag][$priority][$idx] = array('function' => $function_to_add, 'accepted_args' => $accepted_args);
```

Answer (score 0):

> but what does the_content filter do?

The content_filter enables you to return custom content before or after the content.

2 very basic practical examples of using the_content filter in a custom function are as follows:

**This example returns custom content before the content**

```
 add_filter( 'the_content', 'return_before_content' ); 

 function return_before_content( $content ) { 

    if ( is_singular('post')) {

        $before_content = '<p>Text Returned Before the_content</p>';

        $content = $before_content . $content;

        }

    return $content;
}
```

**This example returns custom content after the content**

```
 add_filter( 'the_content', 'return_after_content' ); 

 function return_after_content( $content ) { 

    if ( is_singular('post')) {

         $after_content = '<p>Text Returned After the_content</p>';

        $content = $content . $after_content;

        }

    return $content;
}
```