# Where can I find the code how wordpress parses a post?

Tags: posts, html-editor

When you write a post in `text` section instead of `visual` WordPress will work with HTML. But when you save the post and preview it, it will transform your HTML-like text into real HTML with proper paragraphs etc. Where can I find the code how WordPress does this?

I need that algorithm to transform some text from HTML into HTML of my own that's coming from WordPress posts.

Comment: [TinyMCE](https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE). Is it you are looking for?

Comment: The content in the Visual Editor is processed through TinyMCE http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-tinymce-tweaks/ but the output is sent through quite a few filters http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51749/84219

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific function you are referring to is [`wpautop`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop), which adds paragraphs & HTML linebreaks to already intermixed HTML & plain text.

`wpautop` is part of a family of content-processing functions hooked to [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content), a filter applied to the post content after pulling from the database just before outputting. Taking a look at `wp-includes/default-filters.php`, you can see the default functions are:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize'                       );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'convert_smilies'                   );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop'                           );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop'                 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prepend_attachment'                );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wp_make_content_images_responsive' );
```

You can remove them with `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'name_of_function' )`, and add your own with `add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_function' );` - see [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) for more information on adding filters.

Comment: Perfect, code for wpautop was exactly what I was looking for!